# C++ How to search files in a directory with certain name?

Tags: c++

I want to find files that start with certain words. For example `abc`, `abc22424`, `abc44646`, `abc353535`.

I found this on another question as starting point. Please help me, I am new to C++.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getdir (string dir, vector<string> &files)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
      cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
      return errno;
    }
    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
      files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string dir = string("C:\\test");
    vector<string> files = vector<string>();

    getdir(dir,files);
    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < files.size();i++)
      cout << files[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want display only the files starting with "abc" ? your question is nop clear. Get a look at [regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: i want to display files which name only start with abc.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you ostensibly haven't made much effort, neither to explain your exact requirements nor to attempt to solve them and explain what you tried that didn't work, how it failed etc..  If you requirement is to find files with a specific prefix, you could put add a `const char* prefix"` parameter to `getdir` then `if (strncmp(dirp->d_name, prefix, strlen(prefix)) == 0)` in front of your `files.push_back...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can get file names.
Just compare a file name.

```
while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
std::string fname = dirp->d_name;
if(fname.find("abc") != std::string::npos)
    files.push_back(fname);
}
```

Also you can use scandir function which can register filter function.

```
static int filter(const struct dirent* dir_ent)
{
    if (!strcmp(dir_ent->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dir_ent->d_name, "..")) return 0;
    std::string fname = dir_ent->d_name;

    if (fname.find("abc") == std::string::npos) return 0;

    return 1;
}



int main()
{
    struct dirent **namelist;

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator  it;

    n = scandir( dir_path , &namelist, *filter, alphasort );

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        std::string fname = namelist[i]->d_name;

        v.push_back(fname);

        free(namelist[i]);
    }
    free(namelist);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use scandir function like my code, you should check n variable. It could be return 0 and negative number. That is just simple example.